# Тип связи при нескольких придаточных

Tags: грамматика

*Решил опять подстраховаться по итогам обсуждения*.

**~1. Дана фраза:**

1.a) *Я забыл, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить.*

Сомнений в грамматике нет? Подчиненные однородные? Если да, на какой вопрос отвечают?

**~2. Даны усложненные фразы:**

2.a) *Я забыл, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить, того, кто дал мне все*.

2.б) *Я забыл, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить, а также того, кто дал мне все*.

2.в) *Я забыл отца, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить, а также того, кто дал мне все*.

2.г) *Я забыл отца, маму, бабушку, семью, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить, а также того, кто дал мне все*.

Возникает ли где-то нарушение грамматики, если да, то почему?
Если нет, то однородны ли тут придаточные?

Хотелось бы сухих академических ответов, без лишних слов и примеров. Что непонятно, сам переспрошу.

Answer (score 2):

1.a) Я забыл ( о чём?), кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить.Сомнений нет, это однородное подчинение.

При однородном подчинении придаточные относятся к ОДНОМУ слову или ко всему предложению в целом(к грамматической основе, а чаще к сказуемому). Если относятся к разным словам, это неоднородное подчинение.

2.a) Я забыл(о чём?), кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить,(кого?) того, кто дал мне все.- сложноподчинённое с однородным и неоднородным подчинением(4 придаточных относятся к сказуемому в главном предложении, одно к указательному слову в главном) .

Грамматической ошибки нет, но погрешность имеется: если в главном есть одно соотносительное слово, к которому относится придаточное,то должно быть и второе, к которому относятся остальные придаточные, чтобы убрать неясность содержания: это один человек, их много или последнее обобщает предшествующие(тогда перед "того" должно быть тире).

2.б) Я забыл, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить, а также того, кто дал мне все.Смысл прояснился отчасти, только неясно, тот ли он, что вкладывал автор (того, кто воспитывал и прочее, а также того, кто дал всё). Подчинение однородное и неоднородное.

2.в) Я забыл отца, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить, а также того, кто дал мне все.Неясный смысл. Если речь идёт только об отце, есть грамматическая ошибка - неверно выбрано союзное слово: Я забыл отца, который меня воспитывал..."а также того"вообще лишнее, оно присоединяет факт наличия ещё кого-то, кто дал всё.

Нужно построить так:  Я забыл отца, который меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить и  кто дал мне все.

Если это разные лица, необходимы соотносительные слова, к которым относятся придаточные.

2.г) Я забыл отца, маму, бабушку, семью, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить, а также того, кто дал мне все. Неясно, к чему относятся придаточные. Отец, мама, бабушка - это семья. Если к слову "семья", тогда союзное слово должно быть "которая", а перед обобщающим словом "семья" тире. Последнее придаточное вновь указывает на присоединение(а также), а значит на какое-то ещё лицо, которое дало всё.

Если же всё говорится о семье, возможно построить предложение так:Я забыл отца, маму, бабушку, семью - тех, кто меня воспитывал, кого я должен благодарить, кому я всем обязан, о ком должен помнить и  кто дал мне все.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо. Ву же понимаете, что я сироил фразу не в расчете на "как можно ещё", а принципиально: есть или грамматическая ошибка и главный вопрос - в трактовке неоднородности*.  То что там смысловая неоднозначность - это понятна, но с этим ничего не поделаешь, она изначально там есть.  Будем считать, что там про одну персону речь идет.

Comment: Из вашего ответа, я не понял, где начинается неоднородность, с какого номера. А главное - почему она начинается. *2.б) ... Подчинение однородное и неоднородное.* - Почему? Что изменилось-то? Хотя ладно, это в общем детали. Смысл понятен, грамматика не нарушена.

Comment: Неоднородность + однородность во всех под цифрой 2, т.к.4 придаточных соединены однородным подчинением, они отвечают на один вопрос и относятся к одному главному предложению, к сказуемому в нём, а пятое придаточное отвечает на другой вопрос и относится к другому слову в главном.

Comment: Я не знаю, как считать верной грамматику, если она неверно отражает содержание? Наверное, это всё-таки содержательная ошибка, но ведь причина её - построение предложения. Считается же грамматической ошибка в построении предложения с однородными членами: Он делал не только правильные выводы, а также и предположения.(Разрушен союз "не только, но и" ) Что-то вроде и у Вас:Забыл, кто, кому,кого..., а также того, кто. Разрушена предполагаемая однородность придаточных, значит, всё же грамматическая ошибка.

Comment: А кто знает, какое содержание-то? Грамматика формально верная, если есть хоть одно содержание, которое она передаёт.  Иначе это уже семантика. Ладно, спасибо.